# Uploading to MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Are there any plugins for the latest version of mediawiki that allow you to upload PDFs and other files?

I have one that does images and adds thumbnails but mediawiki does not seem to have something for file uploads.

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki supports natively uploading of any file. This [page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aConfiguring_file_uploads) explains how to configure it.